# OnPressed Set activeColor to a button of a list, and set inactiveColor to others btns - Flutter

Tags: colors, flutter, onclick, android-chips, onpress

I have a list of Chips, and I want them to change color when user click on them.

For instance if I click on the first Chip its color become black, and every other chips are grey. Then if I click on the second Chip its color become black and first Chip color become grey and so on.

I can't find a beautiful/simple way to do this, have you any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
  Widget _myChip(int number, String name) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new Chip(
            label: new Text(name,
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: selectedChip == number ? Colors.white : Colors.black
            ),),
            backgroundColor:
                selectedChip == number ? Colors.black : Colors.grey),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedChip = number;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Stackoverflow'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _myChip(1, 'Arnold'),
          _myChip(2, 'Sylvester'),
          _myChip(3, 'Priscilla'),
          _myChip(4, 'Parge'),
          _myChip(5, 'Something'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

You need to give chips a unique number to identify and use inline if to change the color of the chips.